# Routing issue using Ubuntu

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

Using the typical ZF2 Skeleton Application in Ubuntu with VirtualBox.

The home page in `mysite/public/` works well.
BUt when I write for example `mysite/public/application` returns Not found.

**Not the ZF2 404 page but the default apache not found page.**

```
The requested URL /projects/mysite/public/application was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

It exits ZF2 for some reason.,,

I didn't setup a virtual server

Comment: you should explain me where to ask this question if it's off-topic before using the nerdy lame downvote.

Answer (score 1):

you just answered your own question :

> I didn't setup a virtual server

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html